Always Could not resolve dependencies for project: net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0
I attempted to the build maven with vscode, However, when I want to add dependencies, i always failed. Here is my error message. It seems to be because the package is not in mirror and i have added the local repository into the setting.xml but it does not work. I tried to get definition of the dependency, but it points to the .m2\repository. Why is this happening, I've already set up the local repository.
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 was not found in http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of alimaven has elapsed or updates are forced 

Here is my pom.xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

Here is the basic setting of maven where rep is my local repository.
    "java.configuration.maven.globalSettings": "D:\\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\\apache-maven-3.8.8\\rep\\settings.xml",
    "java.configuration.maven.userSettings": "D:\\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\\apache-maven-3.8.8\\rep\\settings.xml",
    "maven.executable.path": "D:\\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\\apache-maven-3.8.8\\bin\\mvn",

I also add the local repository in the settings.xml <localRepository>D:/apache-maven-3.8.8-bin/apache-maven-3.8.8/rep/repository</localRepository>
My maven version is 3.8.8, I can build it with IDEA. Thanks!
Here is an output of executing mvn -U verify with powershell
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO]
> --------------------------< com.example:demo >-------------------------- [INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]   from pom.xml [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
> ]--------------------------------- Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/imagej/imagej/2.3.0/imagej-2.3.0.pom
> Downloading from jitpack.io:
> https://jitpack.io/net/imagej/imagej/2.3.0/imagej-2.3.0.pom [WARNING]
> The POM for net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 is missing, no dependency
> information available Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/imagej/imagej/2.3.0/imagej-2.3.0.jar
> Downloading from jitpack.io:
> https://jitpack.io/net/imagej/imagej/2.3.0/imagej-2.3.0.jar [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  2.091 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2024-10-04T13:34:44+08:00 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project com.example:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT [ERROR]
> dependency: net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 (compile) [ERROR]        
> Could not find artifact net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 in central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) [ERROR]         Could not find
> artifact net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 in jitpack.io
> (https://jitpack.io) [ERROR] [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To
> see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
> logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
> possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
> 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException


you have to force updates

Just try on plain command line (not inside your IDE's console window) mvn -U verify afterwards upgrade your Maven version to most recent 3.9.9 ...

@khmarbaise hello, I have followed your answer and used PowerShell on the Windows11 to carry out mvn -U verify. But still did not work. Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT Could not find artifact net.imagej:imagej:jar:2.3.0 in aliyunmaven (https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public)

That sounds those dependencies are not in the referenced repository .... Also can you post an output during mvn -U verify ... ?

@khmarbaise hello, I have updated the output and it looks like the imagej is not in the repository. I add the https://jitpack.io in my customized pom.xml but still not work. This dependency works well with IDEA bundled maven. Shall I using the .m2\setting.xml?

The season is the required dependency did not exist in the Maven Central Repository. Maybe I need to add some mirror to get it...
